# A name for a group with finite abelization?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let us recall that a group $G$ is called *perfect* if it coincides with its commutator subgroup $G'$, or equivalently, if its abelianization $G/G'$ is trivial.

> **Question.** Is there any name for a group $G$ whose abelianization $G/G'$ is finite?

Comment: You could call them virtually perfect.

Comment: @DanPetersen I don't think that's a good idea. That would mean having a perfect subgroup of finite index, which is not necessarily the case for groups with $G/G'$ finite.

Comment: If a group is virtually perfect, then it indeed has finite abelianization. What about the converse? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: Yes there are many counterexamples. The infinite dihedral group is solvable and so has no nontrivial perfect subgropus, but it has finite abelianization.

Comment: On the other hand, it is common to say that a group has Property "(FAb)" if *all* its finite index subgroups have a finite abelianization. For instance, finite groups, or the infinite perfect group $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$ have this property, but there are many perfect groups without this property, e.g., the Fuchsian group $\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^3=(ab)^7=1\rangle$.

Comment: I suggest "Wilbur".

Comment: @KeithKearnes Why "Wilbur"?

Comment: @TarasBanakh: Since you force me to invent a justification, here goes. "Wilbur" is the main character of "Charlotte's Web". He is a pig, whose life was spared because he was the smallest in his litter, and then he was lovingly named "Wilbur". I suggest that, since your groups have small abelianization, you lovingly bestow the same name upon them.

Comment: I'd suggest a terminology which (1) makes it clear that it's a weaker variant of being perfect (2) does not seriously/potentially conflict with existing terminology. Bonus if (3) it's flexible. For instance it's natural to consider groups with vanishing first Betti number: these are groups for which the abelianization is torsion, or equivalently for which there is no nontrivial homomorphism into $\mathbf{Q}$, or equivalently trivial $H_1(-,\mathbf{Q})$. Note that this is strictly weaker than finite abelianization. It's useful if one has two related terms for these two notions.

Comment: @YCor Well what about groups $G$ whose abelianization is torsion? How are they called?

Comment: They're called "groups with vanishing first Betti number". But that's not shorter than "groups with torsion abelianization".

Comment: I suggest “almost perfect” group.  A google search indicates this terminology has been used; for instance, here: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/61487184.pdf .

Comment: @HJRW You can write down your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Sometimes a group is called *indicable* if it admits a non-trivial homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$. For a finitely-generated group, this is equivalent to having infinite abelianization. So for finitely generated groups, your condition could be called "non-indicable". But I wouldn't recommend this terminology...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prompted by the OP, I'm writing my comment as an answer.

I suggest “almost perfect” group. A google search indicates this terminology has been used; for instance, here: core.ac.uk/download/pdf/61487184.pdf .